# How do I open a "custom" command prompt in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, usb-flash-drive, batch

I have a flash drive with subversion, python, php and notepad++ on it along with several of my ongoing projects. I do this to be able to resume work on any PC with an internet connection. Currently I have a .bat file that sets up the necessary paths as well as setting the current directory to my projects folder. I run this .bat file by opening a commend prompt and drag&dropping it in.

Here is what I'd prefer: Opening the .bat file would open the configured command prompt and stay open.

Alternatively my flash drive could contain a shortcut to c:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe with the bat file as an argument (if that is possible)

Any way this could be done would be helpful and timesaving

Comment: I think you'll be running into the problem that the drive letter will not be the same on all machines you're plugging into.

Comment: I'm not hard-coding the location :)

Comment: @slhck: That is not a problem, as you can set the path on the same drive as the batch script using the `%~d0` parameter.  eg. `path %~d0\Utils;%PATH%`

Comment: @paradroid Ah, great, learned something today :)

Comment: How about a simple shortcut to something like `cmd /k x:\setvars.bat` (where `x:` is your flash-drive–letter)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

End the `.bat` file with:

```
cmd
```

or

```
%COMSPEC%
```

Comment: Writing `cmd` made the cmd go into an infinite loop of setting `cd`. `%COMSPEC%` worked wonders though! Thanks

Comment: @Codemonkey: Probably caused by your file being named `cmd.cmd` or `cmd.bat`

Answer (score 2):

[Command Prompt Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/command_prompt_portable) from [Portable Apps](http://portableapps.com/) might be what you are looking for.

> **Features**
>
> Command Prompt Portable is a simple utility that allows you to have a
>   custom command line setup on any Windows computer you come across. It
>   has built in support for the command line interpreters on both Windows
>   95/98/Me and Windows 2000/XP/Vista as well as the ability to customize
>   using simple DOS commands by editing the .bat file within
>   CommandPromptPortable\Data\batch after you've run it once. You can
>   customize the prompt, colors, window title, columns and more. A basic
>   batch file is included with some simple settings.
>
> You can also pass in paths you'd like the command prompt to start in
>   by starting CommandPromptPortable.exe with a command line parameter of
>   the path (Windows 2000 and up only). Advanced users can enable
>   auto-complete by following the directions within the
>   Other\Source\readme.txt file.
>
> **Helpful Tip:** Launch a command prompt with your own portable command
>   line tools in the path by adding SET PATH=%~d0\UtilsDirectory;%PATH%
>   to the batch file and placing your tools in X:\UtilsDirectory

Answer (score 0):

Open notepad and enter:

```
command.com
```

Then save it as `anything.bat`. Open it and use `cmd`.

Comment: `command.com` is *not* the same as the Windows command-prompt. If they use that, then many/most of the enhancements (e.g., filename completion) will be lost, not to mention everything just running slower in general.